# QgsAttributeTableView shows nothing in my QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, attribute-table, pyqt

I have created a plugin using the Plugin Builder plugin, and I tried to adapt it to show a QgsAttributeTable (by following [this example](https://github.com/webgeodatavore/pyqgis-samples/blob/master/gui/qgis-sample-QgsAttributeTableView.py)). I get absolutely no errors or warnings, but it simply shows an empty white box. Do you have any suggestions for what I should try?

```py
class FooDockWidget(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('This_is_the_window_title!!!')

        widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setWidget(widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        layer = iface.activeLayer()
        assert layer is not None

        canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
        attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)
        attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

        attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(canvas, attribute_table_model)
        attribute_table_view = QgsAttributeTableView()
        attribute_table_view.setModel(attribute_table_filter_model)

        layout.addWidget(attribute_table_view)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class lacks of `self`, so, at the end of the instantiation (= end of the `__init__`), the references of the objects without `self` not binded in other objects of the class are destroyed, so not displayed.

Correct the end of your `__init__` with :

```py
        self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        self.vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
        self.attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(self.vector_layer_cache)
        self.attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

        self.attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(self.canvas, self.attribute_table_model)
        self.attribute_table_view = QgsAttributeTableView()
        self.attribute_table_view.setModel(self.attribute_table_filter_model)

        layout.addWidget(self.attribute_table_view)
```